# css3 transition not working with pseudo class focus-within

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to apply transition effect to a div but its not working. I am using bootstrap 3

```
<form class="navbar-form meco-navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group meco-search">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
```

here is the css I am using

```
.meco-search input{
    width:100% !important;
}
.meco-navbar-form{
    width:600px !important; 
}
.meco-search:focus-within{
    width:83% !important;

}
```

In this code the width of input is always 100% and when I click in the input the width of custom-search changes.
It's working fine but I am not able to apply transition effect.
Following are the different css codes which I tried to do this but failed.

```
.meco-search{
    transition-property: width;
    transition-duration: 4s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
.meco-search:active{
    transition-property: width;
    transition-duration: 4s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
.meco-search:focus-within{
    width:83% !important;
    transition-property: width;
    transition-duration: 4s;
    transition-delay: 2s;   
}
```

Please Tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: can you please do a fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `transition` of `width` on `input` tag, you need to remove `!important` from `.custom-search input`.

> When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declarations.

```css
.custom-search input {
  width: 100%;
  transition:width 1s ease;
}

.custom-navbar-form {
  width: 600px !important;
}

.custom-search {
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 4s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}

.custom-search:active {
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 4s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}

.custom-search input:focus{
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form class="navbar-form custom-navbar-form navbar-left">
  <div class="form-group custom-search">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can visit https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within to check browser support for pseudo class :focus-within.

Comment: its not what i asked. you can goto http://fbmedia.in/test/home.htm to see the actual thing

Comment: can you see the link and tell find the problem?

Comment: Please add proper details and codes too. Your HTML mark-up is correct, but can you provide proper css codes. As I could see the same transition issue on input tag on provided link.

Comment: please tell me,what should i do now?

Comment: What I have done is that input is set to 100% always. when i focus on input the width of parent tag increases. i have to apply transition effect which is not working

Comment: Check this jsFiddle, hope you trying this https://jsfiddle.net/b8tk7v9y/

Comment: Welcome :-), but I still suggest you to check and read more about :focus-within for browser support.